# Parsing complex numpy dtypes (i.e. dtypes consisting of an array of tuples) into lists?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy.dtype that resembles the following:

```
dtype([('value1','<f8'),('value2','<f8')...])
```

I'd like to get the first part of each tuple (i.e. the value part) into a list, and the second part of each tuple into a separate list. The dtype object does not appear to be an iterable. How do I go about generating these lists? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate `dtype.descr`:

```
>>> d = np.dtype([('value1','<f8'),('value2','<f8')])
>>> [x[0] for x in d.descr]
['value1', 'value2']
```

and:

```
>>> [x[1] for x in d.descr]
['<f8', '<f8']
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, just found another way. d.names, and d.fields will return those respective dtype attributes